# Find limit of polynomial in detail

Tags: limits

I want to know what is the limit
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n + a)^b}{n^b}$$

Please provide a detailed answer. Regards

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my exercise, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context: What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc. Something to both show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @David The sad part is that this answer, although it should be closed until OP improves it, already has two answers...

Comment: Especially important to getting a good answer is to frame the question well.  What is known about $a,b$?

Answer (score 4):

$$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{(n+a)^b}{n^b}$$
$$=\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\dfrac an)^b$$
$$=(\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\dfrac an))^b$$
$$=(1)^b$$
$$=1$$

Answer (score 1):

By the binomial theorem,

$$\frac{(n + a)^b}{n^b}=\binom b0+\binom b1\frac an+\binom b2\frac{a^2}{n^2}+\binom b3\frac{a^3}{n^3}\cdots+\binom bb\frac{a^b}{n^b}.$$

All terms but the first go to zero.